# ¿Como puedo editar múltiples archivos con Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode

Hola mi duda es si se puede editar múltiples archivos y lineas de código en visual studio code.

ejemplo.
Se que todos los archivos que voy a editar tienen algo como esto:

```
<?php namespaces name;
```

Y quiero editar todos los archivos de la carpeta a esto:

```
<?php namespaces otro/name;
```

Esto se hace muy sencillo en SublimeText pero des afortunadamente no lo puedo utilizar como editor de código en mi trabajo.

Si alguien sabe como o conoce algún ecuatorial por favor compartanmelo, no importa que sea en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar abriendo la carpeta de tu desarrollo `File > Open Folder`, despues en `Edit > Replace in Files` como se muestra en la imagen. El primer renglón en tu caso sería:

```
<?php namespaces name;
```

Y el segundo:

```
<?php namespaces otro/name;
```

Por ultimo accionamos el boton de Replace All (`Ctrl + Shift + 1`)

[image: Reemplazar en todos los archivos]

Espero te funcione, saludos!

Comment: Pero la carpeta la tengo abierta con simple-ftp. Siempre trabajo en un servidor de desarrollo. Nunca en mi equipo local.